# How to make a query using 2 variables/inputs from 2 different drop down lists

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet of data that I've been using query functions in. It has worked great so far for single variables, but now I'm trying to make a query from 2 variables, referencing 2 different drop-down lists.
Right now I'm able to filter by category (Clothing type) and by the employee who onboarded separately, but let's say I want to create a query from a specific employee and category. How would I do that? Right now Im using this formula
`=query(Brands!A5:L, " select * where J = '"&B2&"' ")`
which does exactly what it's supposed to do.

How would I add a 2nd variable to that function?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding you correctly, you should just be able to add another selector to the query:

`=query(Brands!A5:L, " select * where J = '"&B2&"' and [col] = '"&[cell]&"'")`

Replacing  `[col]` and `[cell]` with the proper references.

Please let me know if you have any issues with this